# Keyset does not exist /r /n

Tags: sharepoint-2010, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I was tasked to create a integration service between our SharePoint app and one service provider. One requirement of the service provider I'm going to integrate with is to provide them a public key which they will use to verify my request which was signed using our own private key.

Initially I created a console app which reads the certificate store and gets the private key which to use to sign my request and all. The console app works fine so I decided to move it now within our SharePoint application. Unfortunately it fails in this specific part of the code:

```
key.FromXmlString(privateCert.PrivateKey.ToXmlString(true));
```

The whole code snippet which gets the certificate and does the signing can be found below:

```
        X509Certificate2 privateCert = null;
        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.MaxAllowed);

        var certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "thumbprinthere", true);

        if (certs.Count > 0)
        {
            privateCert = certs[0];
        }

        RSACryptoServiceProvider key = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        key.FromXmlString(privateCert.PrivateKey.ToXmlString(true));

        byte[] sig = key.SignData(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data), CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"));
        string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(sig);
```

**[UPDATE]**

I tried following the steps in this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsnotes/2015/08/13/service-failure-with-cryptographicexception-keyset-does-not-exist/). I first uninstalled my existing private key in the server. I then imported it back to the Certificate store and confirmed that there was a Thumbprint property. After that, I ran findprivatekey.exe and was able to navigate to the MachineKeys folder. From there I added different users ranging from Network Services, IIS_IUSRS and even local accounts I used to login to the server as well as SPFarm admin but I still keep getting the error.

I also made sure that the key I added was exportable so there should be a way for it the application to extract the private key attached to the certificate.

**[UPDATE 2]**

I updated the code so that it just returns one certificate prior to assigning it to the variable I was using to extract the private key. Still the same issue even if I can see that the `certs` variable is returning exactly one record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much checking I realized I missed one important part in calling the method code block above. I forgot to wrap it an elevate privilege block. After doing that, the code functioned similarly as my console app.

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate())
{
    ...

    X509Certificate2 privateCert = null;
    X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.MaxAllowed);

    var certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "<thumbprinthere>", true);

    if (certs.Count > 0)
    {
        privateCert = certs[0];
    }

    RSACryptoServiceProvider key = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    key.FromXmlString(privateCert.PrivateKey.ToXmlString(true));

    byte[] sig = key.SignData(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data), CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"));
    string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(sig);

    ...
});
```

Comment: I added my codeblock inside the RunWithElevatedPrivileges method. Basically what it does is it runs the codeblock contained within it with Full Control rights even if the user does not have Full Control.

According to MSDN, RunWithElevatedPrivileges run the methods contained within it under the Application Pool Identity. Since I have given my app pool access to the certificate, running the code block within elevated privilege gave me sufficient rights to access the private key of the certificate.